# Get view position in OnCheckedChangedListener

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I currently have a custom `ArrayAdapter` which uses an xml layout file and populates using a passed in `ArrayList<>` of Java objects. In the layout there is a switch which I have called `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. However, inside the listener I am having trouble retrieving the position in the list that the switch came from or even the other views in that row. Either would work fine for me.

I have seen people using a `ViewHolder` but I'm not sure if that will help me do what I want or not. Here is my adapter code.

```jv
    public class AlarmAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Alarm>  {
    Context context;
    TextView alarmId;
    TextView repeatDaysText;
    public AlarmAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList){
        super(context, R.layout.alarm_layout, alarmList);
        this.context =context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Get the data item for this position
        Alarm alarm = getItem(position);

        //Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.alarm_layout, parent, false);
        }
        //sets the widgets to correspond to variables

        //Set hidden id reference
        alarmId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden_alarm_id);
        alarmId.setText(String.valueOf(alarm.getId()));

        //Set the time display string
        TextView timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_display_text);
        SimpleDateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        timeText.setText(sdf.format(alarm.getTime()));

        //Set the days repeating on
        repeatDaysText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeat_days_text);
        if(alarm.getClass() == RepeatingAlarm.class){
            String repeatText = UtilityFunctions.generateRepeatText(((RepeatingAlarm)alarm).getRepeatDays());
            if(repeatText != null){
                repeatDaysText.setText(repeatText);
                repeatDaysText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            repeatDaysText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //Set the status of the alarm
        Switch statusSwitch = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activate_alarm_switch);
        statusSwitch.setChecked(alarm.getStatus());

        statusSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                if(isChecked){
                    //Activate alarm
//                    AlarmController.getInstance().activateAlarm(context,/*some id*/);
                } else{
                    //Deactivate alarm
//                    AlarmController.getInstance().cancelAlarm(context,/*some id*/);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem of using the `position` parameter of your `getView()` method inside your listener?

Answer (score 0):

```
  ListView mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    for (int position = 0; position <mListView.getChildCount();position ++){
        cb = (CheckBox) mListView.getChildAt(position ).findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);
        if(cb.isChecked()){
            // doSomething  with the position
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilize `Alarm checkedAlarm = getItem(position);` to get my alarm object and then from there retrieve the alarm id I needed for the controller. I called it first thing inside the on checked listener